# Minor Upgrade Patch Issue

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, msi-patch

I have created a installer with version 5.2.1, patch 5.2.2 adds some new components to an existing feature, while installing patch 5.2.3 one of my features is not installting. Its state is Advertise because the log suggests one of the components added by 5.2.2 has been removed from 5.2.3.
I have checked the MSI with version 5.2.3 and by opening the patch 5.2.3 on MSI 5.2.2 there are absolutely zero changes to the component. The guid, keypath all are the same. Can anyone help what might be the cause that my installer is detecting that the component is deleted from the patch?

Comment: Try running your minor upgrade or patch with [MSIENFORCECOMPONENTUPGRADERULES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370093.aspx)=1 (or the related policy), and see if the log tells you anything.

Comment: Did that and it says a component is missing, checked the logs and I found a SELMGR warning that a component has been deleted but when I compare all the installers MSI of 5.2.2, MSI of 5.2.3 and Patch 5.2.3. All have this component with the same GUID, directory and a CreateFolder entry. From 2 days I am struggling to find a mismatch which might be causing this issue!